# how to keep the product selected when I go to the other component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 different component that create a invoice.

1. Component that add more products
2. Component that add invoices detail

In first I write invoices detail, and select client name. For select name I have a autocomplete that search on it. In second when I select one client in view show more details from this client. In past, I add product in different component, when I click submit I navigate in invoice. In this part my client name and more details lost.

Html Code:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
      <input formControlName="client_id" id="client_id"   matInput placeholder="Select Client*" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
        autoActiveFirstOption [formControl]="client_id">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayWith" >
        <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateClient($event, item.client_id, 'client_id')" *ngFor="let item of filteredOptionsClient | async"
          [value]="item.clientName">
          {{ item.clientName }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </div>
  <div class="input-field col s12">
         Contact No:
        <span style="color:darkblue">{{selectedClient.contactno}}</span>
      </div>
```

TS Code:

```
  filteredOptionsClient: any;
  client_id: FormControl = new FormControl();
 ngOnInit() {
    this.cs.getAllClients().subscribe(
      client => {
        this.client = client.map((clients) => {
          this.filteredOptionsClient = this.client_id.valueChanges.pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(val => this.filterClient(val))
          );
          return new Client(clients);
        });
        }
      }
    );
}
  updateClient(ev: any, idd: any, componentid: any) {
    if (ev.isUserInput) {
      if (componentid === 'client_id') {
        this.clientid = idd;
        console.log('idd', idd)
        this.addsale['controls']['client_id'].setValue(ev.source.value);
      } else {
        console.log('ooops');
      }
    }
     let selectedClient = new Client('')
     this.selectedClient = null;
     for (let i = 0; i < this.client.length; i++) {
       console.log('updateclient', this.client[i].client_id)
       console.log('updateclientidd', idd)
       if (this.client[i].client_id === idd) {
         this.selectedClient = this.client[i];
       }
     }
  }
```

Can you ask me any idea how to solution this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to access data across components. According to [this](https://medium.com/dailyjs/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb) link there are following ways

1. Passing the reference of one component to another Communication

   2.through parent component

   3.Communication through Service

Read the above article, you'll reach somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is lik in this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9sijka-wdqwz1?file=app/autocomplete-display-example.ts  1. Select name, add invice name and description. 2 Click add product, write some detail and 3. click submit product. In the end You can't se name of client that selected in first.